# Jssor slider - not resizing on iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, jssor

I use several jssor sliders on several websites and all have the same problem: resizing works fine on every mobile device except iphone! It works fine on any iphone simulator/emulator on the internet, but if I use a real smartphone, the pictures don't resize at all. Does anybody have an idea?
My responsive code is:

```
function ScaleSlider() {
var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
if (parentWidth)
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.max(Math.min(parentWidth, 980), 300));
else
window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
}
ScaleSlider();
$(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
$(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

Thanks & regards
Jochen